# How to check that an input is a decimal?

Tags: python, input

I would like an input to keep asking for an input unless the input is a number with two or less decimals.

```
number = input('please enter a number')  
while number **is not a decimal (insert code)**:  
. . . .number = input('incorrect input,\nplease enter a number')
```

Comment: You could check with this regex `\d*\.\d{1,2}`, but it seems unclean to use regex for this problem :)

Comment: by "two or less decimals" do you mean only two digits after the decimal point?  i.e. `1234151651.12` is okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use a regex as mentioned in the comments:

```
import re

def hasAtMostTwoDecimalDigits(x):
    return re.match("^\d*.\d{0,2}$", x)

number = input("please enter a number")
while not hasAtMostTwoDecimalDigits(number):
    number = input("incorrect input,\nplease enter a number")
```

or use `decimal` module:

```
from decimal import Decimal

def hasAtMostTwoDecimalDigits(x):
    x = Decimal(x)
    return int(1000*x)==10*int(100*x)

number = input("please enter a number")
while not hasAtMostTwoDecimalDigits(number):
    number = input("incorrect input,\nplease enter a number")
```

As noted by [Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) in the comments this can be made even simpler:

```
def hasAtMostTwoDecimalDigits(x):
    return Decimal(x).as_tuple().exponent >= -2
```

Comment: @JonClements Wow, that's neat!

Answer (score 1):

Since `input` gives you a string, it seems most straightforward to treat it as one and just do

```
while len(number.partition('.')[2]) <= 2:
```

Though really you should encapsulate this into a function that checks that it is a completely valid number.  Just doing the above would allow stuff like `123..` through.  So you could do something like:

```
def is_valid(num):
    try:
        float(num)
        return len(a.partition('.')[2]) <= 2
    except Exception:
        return False
```

Where we let `float(num)` handle whether `num` looks like a valid float.

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
if (yourinput%.01 != 0):
```

in other words, if there is anything after the 2nd place decimal...